How does an unbalanced spinning mass fly when released?
A solid mass is being spun about an axis A, but the center of mass C is offset somewhat from the center of spin A.  The mass breaks free of the spin axis instantaneously.  I believe that this results in the mass flying away in a straight line (assuming vacuum, so no Magnus forces).  In what direction does the mass fly?  My guess is that it flies in whatever direction the center of mass was moving, tangent to the center of spin, as shown in the following diagram:

But it also seems like there must be a transitional moment that depends on the distance between A and C and the rate of spin, and that will produce some epicyclic motion about the average direction of travel, so many (if not all) points on the mass do not move in a straight line.  Is this correct, and if so what is the equation of its motion in this scenario?

Newton's first law: If no forces act on it, why would it not move in a straight line?

@VincentThacker I suspect that there is some (possibly imaginary) point that moves in a straight line.  I wouldn't be surprised if it is the center of mass that moves in a straight line.  But I'm asking because I'm not sure.

@VincentThacker would there not be a torque present due to conservation of angular momentum?

@feetwet The point that moves in a straight line is the center of mass. The rest of the object rotates about it. That's all there is to it. I'm not sure what else you are asking. What do you mean by "transitional moment"?

@VincentThacker It's not obvious to me that there can be an instantaneous shift from rotation about A to rotation about C.  But I'm no physicist, so I'm happy to accept your assertion that it is obvious.
